# Activating an existing virtualenv through bash

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

I have installed `virtualenvwrapper` on my Debian machine and followed a guide to install the project I meant to put in this environment. I was able to launch my project and it worked in its own virutalenv.

I have rebooted my system, and when using `lsvirtualenv -l` I recieve the following prompt:

```
MITMf
=====
```

My question is, How do I activate my project again? I cant seem to find any answer of how can I activate it again as currently I'm not "inside" the virtual environment as I was when I finished my installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`workon` command](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/command_ref.html#workon) allows you to list or change working environments:

> ### Syntax:
>
> `workon [(-c|--cd)|(-n|--no-cd)] [environment_name|"."]`
>
> If no `environment_name` is given the list of available environments is printed to stdout.

So this should do the trick:

```
workon MITMf
```